# Rest API . Help to change ListView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, rest

I have some error with Rest API when started Django project.

The error is
"raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'api.urls' from '/Users/luba/code/library/library_project/api/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

My code:

api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics

from books.models import Book

from .serializers import BookSerializer



class BookAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import BookAPIView


urlpattens = [
    path('', BookAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers


from books.models import Book


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'subtitle', 'author', 'isbn')
```

books/views.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import BookListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BookListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

books/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import Book

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book_list.html'
```

Somebody can explain,  in which staff problem with my code.Will be appreciate!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't include your api urls to main urls.py

You can find it at same folder where your settings.py is located.

```
from django.urls import path, include

from api import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(urls.urlpatterns)),
]
```